# Different Output When Stepping Through Program

Tags: objective-c, pointers, struct

**EDIT:** [Here is](https://gist.github.com/chrissphinx/843cc29e07b8e8e989e9) a gist of the program

I'm completely confused by this, here's my main program:

```
    NSString* binPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/BPlusTree/BinaryCodeIndex.bin"];
    CMCodeIndex* index = [[CMCodeIndex alloc] initWithFile:binPath];

    header* h = [index header];

    NSLog(@"%hd, %hd, %hd, %hd, %hd", h->m, h->r, h->e, h->f, h->k);
```

All the CMCodeIndex class does is read 5 short values from the binary file. It's stored in a struct inside the class. Then I get a pointer to the struct and print out the values.

If I run the program normally, I get unexpected output: 27728, 29557, 29268, 25957, 26157

Not the header values. But when I break at the line `header* h = [index header];` and step with lldb until the print statement I get the correct values: 7, 56, 58, 11, 239

What is going on here? I think the problem is in returning a pointer to the struct and the relevant area in memory being overwritten, but I'm not sure. How can I solve it and still keep returning a pointer instead of a copy of the struct?

Comment: i think it would be useful to paste in your `header` struct definition

Comment: absolutely, I've updated the question with a link to a gist of the full program. Do I need to use malloc()? If so, I can't use the `head = {...}` definition anymore, right? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspected, you should use malloc, you your code becomes something like this:

```
header *head=(header*)malloc(sizeof(header));
head->m=( *(short*)[[binHandle readDataOfLength:2] bytes] );
head->f=( *(short*)[[binHandle readDataOfLength:2] bytes] );
head->k=( *(short*)[[binHandle readDataOfLength:2] bytes] );
head->r=( *(short*)[[binHandle readDataOfLength:2] bytes] );
head->e=( *(short*)[[binHandle readDataOfLength:2] bytes] );
h = head;
```

The reason is that you were assigning the reference to the local variable, which exists only in the method scope. Outside it will return undefined.

Comment: Well, most likely the memory address on the stack has not been overridden yet. As I stated previously, in such situations the result is undefined and seems random(but the proper result is not excluded;)